# Unable to download .mobileConfig on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I've created a configuration profile using the iPhone Configuration Utility which I've placed on a server and enabled the MIME Type for .mobileconfig as **application/x-apple-aspen-config**. The URL to the profile is something like **http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/DeviceProfile.mobileconfig**

Now when I try downloading the file through Safari, I get the error as **Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding**

I'm able to download the file on any computer and also on a Nokia phone. When I try opening the URL in simulator, the spinner in the status bar (3G connectivity)  keeps rotating and I get no error message.

Please note that I'm using iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1

Comment: How did you solve this dude.We are all done but unable to download profile through link.But if we send the profile through mail its working fine.

Comment: Imran: You need to host the profile onto a server and allow its MIME type. Nothing else is required if you're able to install the same profile through email.

Comment: @Sahil getting the same error, profile working perfect by sending mail but when i try it to serve via server then it failed with same error..Please help me to solve this ...thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set security as "Always"
2. Remove all passwords from settings.

Try installing once. If you are able to download, it means there is some problem with the password of the security.

Comment: which password you are referring to?